# How to combine setTimeout() function with jquery stop() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know to use stop() function to force queuing operations. For instance,

```
$(seletor).stop().fadeIn();
```

It prevents multiple fade effects when user triggers the mouseenter or mouseouter events.

 Now I want to use stop() function with setTimeout() function or something else to prevents multiple mimic queuing effects.
Here is HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}

.inner, .inner2{
    width: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}

.inner{
    display: none;
}

.inner2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: green; 
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    //$(".container").stop().on("scroll", function(){
    $(".container").on("scroll", function(){
        $(".inner").stop().fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".inner").stop().fadeOut();
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

And [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t8snnx4/) ftw:)

My purpose is to trigger the setTimeout function to hide the red part when user scroll the div. But as I said before, I do not know how to combine stop() and setTimeout() function together. The red part would fadein and fadeout many times with a sequence when scroll multiple times.

 Please help me, many thanks!

Comment: `$(".inner").stop().fadeOut();` is not a `function`; it is a `jQuery` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to keep fading in/out, you should chain the `.fadeIn().fadeOut()`

Something like this may be more what you're looking for...

```
$(function(){
    var ref = null;
    $(".container").on("scroll", function(){
        clearTimeout(ref);
        $(".inner").stop().fadeIn();
        ref = setTimeout(function(){
            $(".inner").stop().fadeOut();
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

This will keep tacking on fadin/out events for animation, then when you stop scrolling for a second, the stop/fadeout takes hold.

Comment: I saw your change.. I was under the impression you wanted the animation to keep going in/out while scrolling... implemented your changes.